# The arguments object - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arguments

I have ran the below code. But I am supposed to get the minimum number from the data array as -1 but what I am getting is the initialized value of 'min' variable i.e 0

```js
let data = [2,3,4,2,6,7,8,9,-1,7,6,4,3]
let  min = 0

function findMin() {

  for (let n of arguments) {
      if(n < min) {
          min = n
      }
  }
  return min
}

const smallNumber = findMin(data)
console.log(smallNumber)
```

Can someone help to explain ?

Comment: You’re iterating over `arguments`, which is an array-like object of _a single element_. That element is your entire array. You’re comparing a number against your array. Why not do it normally and let `findMin` accept a parameter and iterate over that?

Comment: did you try logging `arguments` or `n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `arguments` is an Array-like object that has entries for each argument the function was called with, with the first entry's index at 0.

Try this snippet

```js
let data = [2, 3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, -1, 7, 6, 4, 3];
let min = 0;

function findMin() {
  for (let n of arguments[0]) {
    if (n < min) {
        min = n;
    }
  }
  return min;
}

const smallNumber = findMin(data);
console.log(smallNumber);
```

Answer (score -4):

You just forgot to declare the parameters in your function!

```
let data = [2,3,4,2,6,7,8,9,-1,7,6,4,3]
let  min = 0

function findMin(arguments) {

  for (let n of arguments) {
      if(n < min) {
          min = n
      }
  }
  return min
}

const smallNumber = findMin(data)
console.log(smallNumber)
```

Comment: The question is about the [the arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), which allows access to all arguments passed to the function even if not declared as paremeters. You have just declared a normal parameter named 'arguments'

Comment: Oh ok sorry sorry, I didn't understand :(